# Where does the ds:Signature element go in a SAML LogoutRequest?

Tags: saml, xml-signature, pingfederate

The PingFederate 6.10 server responds with "Signature required", but the LogoutRequest it receives has a Signature element.  Is it in the wrong place?  How do I get the LogoutRequest to work?

Perhaps also important: The PingFederate server log says "Exception occurred during request processing org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.StatusResponseException: Request was invalid XML".  I don't know which of these errors is accurate; the XML is well-formed, so I've been assuming "Signature required" is the error I should be paying attention to.

(Note that I shortened the X509Certificate, SignatureValue, and Modulus elements' text to make the Request and Response more readable)

Request:

```xml
<samlp:LogoutRequest Destination="https://pingfederate:9031/idp/SLO.saml2" ID="_63d86130-2d0e-0130-c98a-58b035fb0c5e" IssueInstant="2012-12-20T12:04:31Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://localhost:3000/auth/saml/metadata</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
            <ds:Reference URI="#_63d8f1f0-2d0e-0130-c989-58b035fb0c5e">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
                <ds:DigestValue>+7+DaMHOq7Up//Uoizpn5feSIxU=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>aAn0zuawy59ZXOTjx1...VULz7dVRd0g=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>LS0tLS1CR...BVEUtLS0tLQo=</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">jacob</saml:NameID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

Response:

```xml
<samlp:LogoutResponse Destination="http://localhost:3000/auth/saml/logout" ID="oWIAl1CbSxM-H9HZKm2L6LyTSDm" InResponseTo="_cab603f0-2dce-0130-c995-58b035fb0c5e" IssueInstant="2012-12-21T19:01:47.530Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">x</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#oWIAl1CbSxM-H9HZKm2L6LyTSDm">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>7HxtM74mkE/t3/UoR8ehE6Wa6x0=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>iGfTRlj25EYZnI496I5V...LHVJyUdgG4cF71wRT0Q=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIICFzCCAYC...gYl9535grCDQbs/zVY=</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
            <ds:KeyValue>
                <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                    <ds:Modulus>jCMC58LLRg6wQLJQ...VNEll3WQdFPc/hezdjk=</ds:Modulus>
                    <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
                </ds:RSAKeyValue>
            </ds:KeyValue>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
        <samlp:StatusMessage>Signature required</samlp:StatusMessage>
    </samlp:Status>
</samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

Comment: Might be related, perhaps even an answer to your question: https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Administration/A-signed-LogoutRequest-sent-over-Redirect-yields-Signature-required

Answer (score 1):

SAML Assertions and Protocols Specification (http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) says in Section 5.4.2 that the URI attribute of the Reference element must be identical with the ID attribute of the Logout Request element.

In your case, the ID of the Logout Request element is _63d86130-2d0e-0130-c98a-58b035fb0c5e, and the URI of the Reference element is _63d8f1f0-2d0e-0130-c989-58b035fb0c5e. Since these two values are different, PingFederate thinks that the Logout Request is not signed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not acquainted with Ping but in General Saml 2.0 Single Logout Profile is described quite well in [Oasis Documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf) (Page 32).
I am not sure if this is what you need but I hope that It may be helpfull.

Edit 1: On page 20 of [this](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf) document you have sample LogoutRequest with signing